# CORB blocks cross-origin response (wrong MIME type)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mime-types, cross-origin-read-blocking

I currently deployed a ReactJS app and a NodeJS REST API. Users can upload images which are stored on the server itself.

At first I can see the images but after a while I get a CORB error in the console and the images are also not showing. The error says:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://LINK_TO_API/uploads/images/image10.jpeg with MIME type application/json.
```

In other words: it seems that the MIME type is set to application/json which is of course not correct for jpeg files.

How and where can I change this MIME type?

Comment: You set the mime type when you upload the picture, in the React side I think, how are you uploading the pic?

Comment: @ZEE I grab the uploaded file and then append it to formData. The latter is then send, together with other data, to the backend.